# Number mask in SweetAlert2

Tags: angular, mask, sweetalert2

I would like to put a number mask in an input of sweetalert2, can you help me?
my code:

```js
onClick(btn) {
    let code2_fa = '';
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).password.two_factors.is_active) {
      swal({
        title: 'Digite o TOKEN para prosseguir',
        imageUrl: './assets/imgs/Authy.svg',
        imageAlt: 'Logo Authy',
        input: 'text',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Digite o TOKEN...',
        inputAttributes: {
          maxlength: '6',
          autofocus: 'true',
          required: 'true',
        },
        inputValue: code2_fa,
        animation: true,
        allowEnterKey: true,
        inputAutoTrim: true,

      })
  }
```

I am using Angular 6, the intention is to display a modal so that the user can enter their authy code.

Comment: [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) are made for that. Consider using one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use vanilla javascript, you could use the `onBeforeOpen` property of `swal` to register an handler for key press events on the input, e.g.:

```
onBeforeOpen: () => {
  swal.getInput().onkeypress = (event) => {
    return Number.isInteger(parseInt(event.key))
  }
}
```

The above implementation is a very simple key press detector that returns `false` if the key pressed is not a number.

A running implementation of that can be seen at https://three-keeper.glitch.me/